# Fixing the view of display: table property

Tags: html, css

I've tried to add a `display:table` to a parent element (rowcontainer) and `display:table-cell;` to the child element (div1, div2) for over 500px width on screen. This worked, but the padding on the child elements now have to left or right padding, and the bottom row has something off with it, any ideas on how to fix this? :

Here is also a codepen of the problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYxegN

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  .div1,
  .div2 {
    color: blue;
  }
}
   
#pagewrap {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.75);
  border: 1px red solid;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-height: 87.5% height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1,
h2 {
  color: white;
}
p {
  color: silver;
}
#tablecontainer {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .rowcontainer {
    padding: 2.5px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .rowcontainer div {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .div1 {
    padding: 1.25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">

  <div id="tablecontainer">

    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">1</div>
      <div class="div2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">3</div>
      <div class="div2">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">5</div>
      <div class="div2">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">7</div>
      <div class="div2">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">9</div>
      <div class="div2">10</div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: The second cell is bigger as it's based on the length of the content and it has an extra character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, all that is needed is to add

```
 table-layout:fixed
```

in the media query

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 500px){

    .rowcontainer {
    padding:2.5px;
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 5px 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width:100%;
    }
}
```

[**Codepen Updated.**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VYRjzy)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  .div1,
  .div2 {
    color: blue;
  }
}
html {
  background: url(img/nature.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#pagewrap {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.75);
  border: 1px red solid;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-height: 87.5% height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1,
h2 {
  color: white;
}
p {
  color: silver;
}
#tablecontainer {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .rowcontainer {
    padding: 2.5px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .rowcontainer div {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .div1 {
    padding: 1.25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">

  <div id="tablecontainer">

    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">1</div>
      <div class="div2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">3</div>
      <div class="div2">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">5</div>
      <div class="div2">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">7</div>
      <div class="div2">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">9</div>
      <div class="div2">10</div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: How would I go about adding padding in the middle of the divs?

Comment: What would the padding be for?

Comment: only for aesthetic purposes really!

Comment: i really need to see what this supposed to look like..it's not clear to me what  padding **in the middle** actually looks like.

Comment: I meant adding a small border between div1 and div2, which allows you to see the elements behind it, like for example how the border works between the columns in http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/table/table.jpg (ps just google'd for this image).

Comment: exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct structure is like this for CSS table.

```
#tablecontainer {
    display:table; /*behaves like <table>*/
}
.rowcontainer {
    display:table-row; /*behaves like <tr>*/
}
.rowcontainer div {
    display:table-cell; /*behaves like <td>*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this stabilised the widths, but what would i do to make them 50% each and re-establish the padding? around each child div (div1 and div2)?

Comment: I fixed the width problem but simply adding `width:50%` to `.rowcontainer div{`, however the padding problem still occurs, I will play around with it and get back to you.

Comment: @Gphillips1 see this updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/wcns64t2/ added border-spacing: 10px;

Comment: thanks for the input, i believe you are right about the structure, so I will upvote onec I get 15 rep, but Paulie was closest to what I wanted, appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  .div1,
  .div2 {
    color: blue;
  }
}
   
#pagewrap {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.75);
  border: 1px red solid;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-height: 87.5% height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1,
h2 {
  color: white;
}
p {
  color: silver;
}
#tablecontainer {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .rowcontainer {
    padding: 2.5px;
    display: table-row;
  }
  .rowcontainer div {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .div1 {
    padding: 1.25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">

  <div id="tablecontainer">

    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">1</div>
      <div class="div2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">3</div>
      <div class="div2">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">5</div>
      <div class="div2">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">7</div>
      <div class="div2">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowcontainer">
      <div class="div1">9</div>
      <div class="div2">10</div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: That's quite a bit of code to parse through and figure out what you've changed.  It would be very helpful to explain what is different about your code that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct in making a table with div. The above problem is because of the text. (Last cell has 2 digit text, if you make it one digit it works fine ). To fix this issue use below code. **In the rowcontainer just add width.**

```
.rowcontainer div{
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%
    }
```

Your complete code can be seen on http://codepen.io/gauravshankar/pen/OPqXga